# Get ID of Last Inserted Record

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having an issue retrieving the `order_id` from the last inserted record in a table I have called 'orders'.

Once retrieved, I would like such to be put into my other table named 'reports'.

I can see this question has been asked numerous times and I have instituted as much of the advice without success.

Currently, each of my tables has the auto_increment attribute included and my function performs a successful INSERT on the 'orders' table (not the reports table however to which I am trying to achieve.

[image: orders]

[image]

```
function report() {



if(isset($_GET['tx'])) {  

$amount = $_GET['amt']; 
$currency = $_GET['cc'];
$transaction = $_GET['tx']; 
$status = $_GET['st']; 
$total = 0;  
$item_quantity = 0; 




$send_order = query(" INSERT INTO orders (order_amount, order_transaction, order_status, order_currency) VALUES('{$amount}','{$currency}','{$transaction}','{$status}')");


$last_id = last_id(); // this calls last_id in functions.php


confirm($send_order);  




foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) { 


if($value > 0 ) { 


if(substr($name, 0, 8) == "product_") { 


$length = strlen($name - 8); 

$id = substr($name, 8 , $length);




$query = query(" SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = " . escape_string($id). " " );

confirm($query);



while ($row = fetch_array($query)) {

$product_price = $row['product_price'];
$sub = $row['product_price']*$value;
$item_quantity +=$value;



$insert_report = query(" INSERT INTO reports (product_id, order_id, product_price, product_quantity) VALUES('{$id}','{$last_id}','{$product_price}','{$value}')");
confirm($insert_report); //runs the confirm helper method  




} // end of while loop


$total += $sub; 
echo $item_quantity; 


} // end of substring if statement




}// end of if value




} // end of foreach loop


session_destroy();

} else {


redirect("index.php");


} //end of if isset GET tx




} // end of report function /////////////////
```

**functions.php**

```
function last_id() {

global $connection;

return mysqli_insert_id($connection);



}
```

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_  to SQL injections and should use Prepared Statements instead of building your queries like that. Specially since you don't even escape the user input in any way.

Comment: thank you for the steering....

Comment: Why not accept a parameter in your function which takes the link, instead of using `global [...]`. So it would go something like `last_id($link)`.

Comment: @Script47 can you show me how you might refactor that please

Comment: Make sure that the mysqli_insert_id($connection); is made *after* the insert statement in order to retrieve the last id.

Comment: @Martin the mysqli_insert_id($connection); is abstracted in the functions.php page, and not nested in the above report function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqli_insert_id($send_order)` after insert query in your php page.

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
$last_id = last_id();
```

**after** you use

```
confirm($send_order);
```

Comment: How would this help? Why would it work after `confirm`?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

$send_order = query(" INSERT INTO orders (order_amount, order_transaction, order_status, order_currency) VALUES('{$amount}','{$currency}','{$transaction}','{$status}')");

$last_id = $send_order->insert_id;